# Android App crashes after backpress with Handler and Camera

Tags: android, android-camera, onbackpressed

Android App crashes after backpress with Handler and Camera

I am trying to use camera for an SOS app , the code runs when we start the sos flash using the button click in order to keep the flash light running , I am using Handler with Post delay

the app crashes when we use backpress to go back to the previous activity

I have tried using  `handler.removeCallbacks(r);` , onbackpress but still the app crashes

this is the code I am trying

```
public class sos extends Activity {
    String myMorseString = "111000111";
    int sleepTime;
    Camera cam;
    Handler handler;
    Runnable r;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sos);
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Start);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                startsos();
            }
        });
    }

    public void startsos() {
        // new Thread() {
        handler = new Handler();
          r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (myMorseString != null) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < myMorseString.length(); x++) {

                        if (myMorseString.charAt(x) == '2') {
                            cam = Camera.open();
                            sleepTime = 500;
                            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
                            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                            cam.setParameters(p);
                            cam.startPreview();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            }
                            // power off after signal
                            cam.stopPreview();
                            cam.release();
                            cam = null;
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                            }
                        }

                        if (myMorseString.charAt(x) == '1') {
                            cam = Camera.open();
                            sleepTime = 250;
                            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
                            p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                            cam.setParameters(p);
                            cam.startPreview();
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            // power off after signal
                            cam.stopPreview();
                            cam.release();
                            cam = null;
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        if (myMorseString.charAt(x) == '0') {
                            cam = Camera.open();
                            sleepTime = 250;
                            Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
                            cam.setParameters(p);
                            //cam.startPreview();
                            cam.stopPreview();
                            cam.release();
                            cam = null;

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
            // }.start();


        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: I think calling `finish()` in `onBackPressed` is the problem. When calling `super.onBackPressed()`, you're activity will be finished. By calling `finish()` explicitly, I think you're introducing the error. You can remove `finish()` as `super.onBackPressed()` will also destroy your activity

Comment: without using finish also the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely crashing because the camera preview isn't being stopped when back is pressed.  The `Runnable` is just being removed from the `Handler`.

That being said, you're also going to see another problem: creating a `Handler` from within an `onClick()` handler isn't creating a new thread.  It's still creating a `Handler` which is bound to your main thread.  The `onClick()` (and any view related callback) is called on the main (UI) thread.  So the `sleep()` calls you are making in the `Runnable` are happening on your main thread, which is very bad.

Comment: could you explain in code with the above code I tried the following  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //cam = Camera.open();
        Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.setParameters(p);
        cam.stopPreview();
        cam.release();
        cam = null;
        Thread.interrupted();
         super.onBackPressed();
    } , now the flash wont stop

Comment: Unfortunately, some devices can be very picky about how this works.  For example, on some devices you do not need to have the preview started, but on others you do.  You may want to look at using the `Camera2` API instead as the original `Camera` API has been deprecated.